# List comprehension - combine definitions of duplicate words so that each word is unique but may have more than one definition

Tags: python, python-3.x

> I have a two dimensional list of words and their respective definitions. As you can see in the example below, some words appear more than once but with different definitions. I would like to combine the definitions of duplicate words so that each word only appears once.

```
list_of_lists = [
  ['absorption', 'a process in which one substance permeates another'],
  ['absorption', 'when radiated energy is retained on passing through a medium'],
  ['aerobic', 'depending on free oxygen or air'],
  ['aerobic', 'enhancing respiratory and circulatory efficiency'],
  ['chain reaction', 'a self-sustaining nuclear reaction'],
  ['chain reaction', 'a series of chemical reactions in which the product of one is a reactant in the next']
]
```

> Expected output after some programming magic:

```
['absorption', 'a process in which one substance permeates another', 'when radiated energy is retained on passing through a medium']
['aerobic', 'depending on free oxygen or air', 'enhancing respiratory and circulatory efficiency']
['chain reaction', 'a self-sustaining nuclear reaction', 'a series of chemical reactions in which the product of one is a reactant in the next']
```

Comment: What you tried?

Comment: And what is the exact format of your data? Your examples are not valid python.

Comment: To be perfectly honest, I don't even know how to start. I'm just getting started with python.

Comment: What you have is *not* a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Frankly, I have no idea what it is; it is not Python.

Comment: It's not valid python. I don't exactly have any code at this moment and I'm completely new to StackOverflow and the formatting options are kind of overwhelming.

Comment: You don't even have a formal problem statement.

Comment: If the input a text file? A list? It is impossible to help without specific details.

Comment: Sorry, but I really don't know how else to word it. I haven't seen any similar problems on SOF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this is your data:

```py
list_of_lists = [
  ['absorption', 'a process in which one substance permeates another'],
  ['absorption', 'when radiated energy is retained on passing through a medium'],
  ['aerobic', 'depending on free oxygen or air'],
  ['aerobic', 'enhancing respiratory and circulatory efficiency'],
  ['chain reaction', 'a self-sustaining nuclear reaction'],
  ['chain reaction', 'a series of chemical reactions in which the product of one is a reactant in the next'],
]
```

You could use a `groupby` expression like so:

```py
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

for key, group in groupby(list_of_lists, itemgetter(0)):
  print([key] + list(map(itemgetter(1), group)))
```

Output:

```py
['absorption', 'a process in which one substance permeates another', 'when radiated energy is retained on passing through a medium']
['aerobic', 'depending on free oxygen or air', 'enhancing respiratory and circulatory efficiency']
['chain reaction', 'a self-sustaining nuclear reaction', 'a series of chemical reactions in which the product of one is a reactant in the next']
```

Comment: That is my data. How did you format it like that? I'm completely new to SOF.

Comment: Standard markdown formatting. Add Triple backticks around your text.

Comment: @turineumann please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and have a look at [this FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)

Comment: That's almost it! But I would like the 'key' to be the zeroth item of the list so that I can join it as a string later.

Comment: Thanks. I'll read it.

Comment: I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Not sure what OP actually wants, but this data structure would be appropriate as a dictionary where the words are the keys and the definitions are the values.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) from the standard collections library to make a dictionary of keys -> list of definitions. This by itself might be useful, but it's also easy to transform to a list of tuples:

```
from collections import defaultdict

l = [
    ('absorption','a process in which one substance permeates another'),
    ('absorption', 'when radiated energy is retained on passing through a medium'),
    ('aerobic', 'depending on free oxygen or air'),
    ('aerobic', 'enhancing respiratory and circulatory efficiency'),
    ('chain reaction', 'a self-sustaining nuclear reaction'),
    ('chain reaction', 'a series of chemical reactions in which the product of one is a reactant in the next')
]

res = defaultdict(list)

for k, v in l:
    res[k].append(v)

# res is a dict so you can look up words:
print(res['aerobic'])
# ['depending on free oxygen or air', 'enhancing respiratory and circulatory efficiency']

# to get back a list of tuples, just pass the dict items to list()
collected_list = list(res.items())

# [('absorption',
#   ['a process in which one substance permeates another',
#   'when radiated energy is retained on passing through a medium']),
# ('aerobic',
#   ['depending on free oxygen or air',
#   'enhancing respiratory and circulatory efficiency']),
# ('chain reaction',
#   ['a self-sustaining nuclear reaction',
#   'a series of chemical reactions in which the product of one is a reactant in the next'])]
```

Comment: This is awesome, dude. Thanks!